# PHP: retrieve all declared namespaces of a DOMElement

Tags: php, dom, xml-namespaces

I am using the [DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse an xml file containing [xml namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml_namespace). I would have thought that namespace declarations are treated just like any other attribute, but my tests seem to disagree. I have a document that starts like this:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
    xmlns:taxo="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/taxonomy/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:syn="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:prism="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/prism/"
    xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
    >
```

And a test code like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXml(file_get_contents('/home/soulmerge/tmp/rss1.0/recent.xml'));
$root = $doc->documentElement;
var_dump($root->tagName);
# prints 'string(7) "rdf:RDF"'
var_dump($root->attributes->item(0));
# prints 'NULL'
var_dump($root->getAttributeNode('xmlns'));
# prints 'object(DOMNameSpaceNode)#3 (0) {}'
```

So the questions are:

1. Does anyone know where could I find the documentation of `DOMNameSpaceNode`? A [search on php.net](http://de.php.net/results.php?q=DOMNameSpaceNode&l=en&p=all) does not yield any useful result.
2. How do I extract all those namespace declarations from that DOMElement?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless there is a more direct way you can use XPath and its [namespace axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes).
e.g.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadxml('<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
    xmlns:taxo="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/taxonomy/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:syn="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:prism="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/prism/"
    xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
    >
...
</rdf:RDF>');
$context = $doc->documentElement;

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach( $xpath->query('namespace::*', $context) as $node ) {
  echo $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

prints

```
http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace
http://webns.net/mvcb/
http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/prism/
http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/
http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/
http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/taxonomy/
http://purl.org/rss/1.0/
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
```

---

edit and btw: I haven't found documentation for DOMNameSpaceNode either. But you can "deduct" (parts of) its functionality from the source code in ext/dom/php_dom.c
It doesn't seem to expose any methods and exposes the properties

```
"nodeName", "nodeValue", "nodeType",
"prefix", "localName", "namespaceURI",
"ownerDocument", "parentNode"
```

all handled by the same functions as the corresponding DOMNode properties.

Comment: Many thanks, this is definitely a working solution. Guess I'll have to wait until the php documentation is updated to get the implementation right.

Comment: Note that `$xpath->query('namespace::*', $context)` lists all namespaces  declared before `$context` element, not just those declared directly in it's attributes. You can filter them using `$context->hasAttribute($node->nodeName)`. Thanks, @driedfruit.

Answer (score 5):

Note, that

```
echo $root->getAttributeNode('xmlns')->nodeValue . "\n";
echo $root->getAttribute('xmlns') . "\n";
echo $root->getAttribute('xmlns:syn') . "\n";
```

all work as expected, and print out

```
http://purl.org/rss/1.0/
http://purl.org/rss/1.0/
http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/
```

because DOMNameSpaceNode is a Node, not a NodeCollection.

Just clarifying, that, unless something in PHP DOM extension changes, XPath (as explained by VolkerK) is the only native way to get all the namespaces, regardless of documentation.