# How to set namespace (xmlns) declaration at root tag, with "pure DOM"?

Tags: php, domdocument

Error "Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Namespace Error'" in

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
 $root = $dom->createElement('MyRoot','Hello');
 $root->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','xmlns:xlink','xlink');
 $dom->appendChild($root);
 die($dom->saveXML());
```

**How to set an `xmlns` declaration at root tag?** to produce

```
  <MyRoot xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>Hello</MyRoot>
```

Comment: For use in fragments, see [this PHP bug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26593430/287948).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace of the xmlns:xlink is not its value, but a standard namespace. The prefix xmlns is used for the standard namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/`. You do not need to define that namespace.

All namespace attributes (except for xmlns="...") are part of this namespace.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$root = $dom->createElement('MyRoot','Hello');
$root->setAttributeNS(
  'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/','xmlns:xlink','http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
);
$dom->appendChild($root);

echo($dom->saveXML());
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyRoot xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">Hello</MyRoot>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the XMLNS namespace, then the attribute name of `xmlns:xlink`, and then the value of the attribute you want to set ... which is the xlink url.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$root = $dom->createElement('MyRoot','Hello');
$root->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/','xmlns:xlink','http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
$dom->appendChild($root);
die($dom->saveXML());

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyRoot xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">Hello</MyRoot>
```

Comment: hello thanks! But what the first (for question-vote), ThW or you?

Comment: Looks like @ThW submitted at `2014-10-27 18:34:08Z` and I submitted at `2014-10-27 18:34:13Z`. ThW beat me to it by 5 seconds.

Comment: Well... there are a new good question related, http://stackoverflow.com/q/26593430/287948

Comment: Got an answer on that one ... kind of weird but it's how it works.