# PHP xmllib XSD validation namespace error: Did not expect X, expected X

Tags: php, domdocument, xsd-validation

I've been trying to get xmllib to cooperate and validate a xmldsig `<Signature>` element via `DOMDocument`, yet it keeps producing spurious errors no matter how I throw the element at it. Apparently having the `<Signature>` be the [root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594261/how-to-set-namespace-xmlns-declaration-at-root-tag-with-pure-dom) is a no-go due to `DOMDocument`. I can't manage to set the `xmlns` attribute on the root properly:  Trying to validate results in:

```
Element 'Signature': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
```

I think It's maybe because the schema is intended to be 'included', you would want to sign 'something'  after all, not just have signature by itself. So, by creating this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    version="1.0"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" />
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="ds:Signature" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I can now have an included signature for a dummy element.

I realize PHP XML processing is rather bad, none of the tools really work all that well. However, once it actually hands things off to xmllint properly, there should be no issue doing this. Other answers suggest adding in XPath as well, but I'd like to keep things KISS; use as little PHP libraries as possible.

With a couple hundred lines of code finagling I got it to cooperate and wrap just the `<Signature>` part of the xml file into a plain test file, inside a `<root>` element.

I think it's doing something to corrupt the namespaces in the document. Calling `$myDocument->saveXML();` after it fails `$myDocument->schemaValidate();` returns a peculiar result:

```
Element 'Signature': This element is not expected. Expected is ( {http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature ).
```

When the xml looks like this (I've added the formatting; the real thing is unformatted; though the whitespace should not be significant):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
         (... omitted crypto ...)
    </Signature>
</root>
```

From the reading I've done on it, the error should mean that the namespace is wrong on the `<Signature>`  element. But here it's clearly explicitly designated with the `xmlns` to be exactly what the error message is expecting it to be. So, what's wrong here?

Addendum: Code to prepare the signature for verification (in an arbitrary document) would look something like this. This is the complicated version where I've added a 'root' element instead of using the schema directly, which, see my answer below, turned out to be unnecessary, although a good test, as in more complicated scenarios where you'd want to validate a signed thing in one call to libxml it's a valid thing to want to do:

```php
function verifySchema(\DOMDocument $doc) {        
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $new = new \DOMDocument; 
    $newRoot = $new->createElement("root");
    $root = $doc->documentElement;     
    foreach($root->childNodes as $node) {   
        if($node->nodeName == "Signature") {
            $signature = $new->createElement("Signature");
            $signature->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/','xmlns','http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#');
            foreach($node->childNodes as $subnode) {
                $signature->appendChild($new->importNode($subnode, true));
            }
            $newRoot->appendChild($signature);
            break;
        }
    }           
    $new->appendChild($newRoot);
    if(!$signature) {
        throw new \Exception("Document is not signed: No signature node found.");
    }
    if(!$new->schemaValidate("xmldsig-test.xsd")) {
       // Error handling code here.
   } else {
       return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Although there may be a large amount of code, can you include a minimal example to show how to re-create the problem.  Despite the large amount of description, it is difficult to know how you created the document that is causing the problem.

Comment: I'll try to come up with a way to strip all the unnecessary info and add a minimal illustrative example. Though dont take this example as the 'only' problem: There's an infinite amount ways of manipulating DOMDocument objects that gives the same output, and initially no amount of changing things around seemed to help. It (now I know it does) points to an underlying problem that causes a family of issues.

Comment: Sometimes php has it's own ideas of how things are done and SO is probably full of workarounds for various *features*.  At least it's a case of documenting them and helping other if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is the problem. It's subtly buggy and won't/doesn't understand XML namespaces properly in programmatically created documents.

There's various ways of adding/editing DOMDocument elements, and some/most of these can lead to an element *E* which is in some namespace *X* when you just look at the XML output, but where the DOMDocument object considers it to be in namespace *Y*. Even if you only use the provided functions and don't access the object's internals it's possible to put them in an inconsistent state. In some cases, if you want the namespaces in a specific **format** (due to canonicalization issues) even unavoidable.

See:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78352

Replace the line of code

```
$myDocument->schemaValidate();
```

with

```
$myDocument->loadXML($myDocument->saveXML());
$myDocument->schemaValidate();
```

and the validation error should be gone. Either way (using a custom `xsd` with include or using the xmldsig validation file directly) should work.

While the bug is seen as 'not a bug', it really is a problem, as `DOMDOcument` won't actually output the exact syntax using a `xmlns` attribute but use the prefix notation instead if you use `createElementNS()`. (While syntactically perhaps the same, nobody understands xml namespaces so people accepting your XML might want it exactly like the example, i.e.: using the `xmlns`, **not** using `ds:Signature` elements).

Instead using `DOMElement::setAttributeNS($currentNS, 'xmlns', $subElementNS)` **does** output a default namespace tag, but does **not** tag the programmatic entities under the element correctly recursively with the new namespace.